# how to send variable to twig

Tags: twig, silex

I ask this question a few day ago, and perhaps I don't explain myself really well.

I'm trying to use Silex2, so I copy the code in the documentation to make my first page.

<kbd>index.php</kbd>

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../config/dev.php';
require __DIR__.'/../src/controllers.php';

$pg_cnt['temp'] = 'Welcome !';
$pg_cnt['name'] = 'tutu';

$app->get('/', function () use ($app, $pg_cnt) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array(
        'pg_cnt' => $pg_cnt,
    ));
});

$app->get('/home', function () use ($app, $pg_cnt) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array(
        'pg_cnt' => $pg_cnt,
    ));
});
$app->run();
```

<kbd>index.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends "arche/layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

{{ global.request }}
    <h1>{{ pg_cnt.temp }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ pg_cnt.name|default('default titi') }}</h1>


<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
{% endblock %}
```

I use the same code for the route `/` and `/home`, but for this one `/` I have an error :

> Twig_Error_Runtime in index.html.twig line 7: Variable "pg_cnt" does
>   not exist.

For the other one `/home`, everything work.

I don't understand what is happening here ?
I'm using the [silex-skeleton](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as is, perhaps try to switch it up to:

```
<?php 
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = require __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../config/dev.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../src/controllers.php';

    $pg_cnt['temp'] = 'Welcome !';
    $pg_cnt['name'] = 'tutu';

    $func = function () use ($app, $pg_cnt) {
        return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array(
            'pg_cnt' => $pg_cnt,
        ));
    };

    $app->get('/', $func);
    $app->get('/home', $func);

    $app->run();
```

Comment: @PaddyF Strange, code should work though. Made a small [sandbox](http://darkbee.be/web/stack.php/)

Comment: I try your sandbox, and it works ! Except I don't see what I need to change in my code so it can work too ? 
I try to change the twig declaration (comment all line in the skeleton and add yours at the same place). 
The error change to : `Twig_Error_Loader in Chain.php line 86:
Template "index.html.twig" is not defined.`
To be clear, the route /home still work perfectly

Comment: I dunno man, the code in the sandbox is the same as yours. Are you sure there isn't any other route registered to `/` in the `app.php`, `dev.php` or `controllers.php`?

Comment: You're right, there is, in the 'controllers.php', the route '/' is configured by default ... 
Thanks a lot Bye

Comment: @PaddyF, [you should accept DarkBee's anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in order to close your question.